# Is there a way to know if the page html is updated?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, events

I am developing a ToDo List, and I need to know if there is a javascript event that lets you know if the items are created. The "load" does not work because I do not reload the page, (AJAX request), I display the elements in javascript and events (for example "click") on these elements.
My problem is that when I display the items, I delete them and redisplay them (because I read a file and write the elements). This means my events are listening to an element that doesn't exist. So I would like to know if there is a way to detect if the elements have been written in HTML so that I can then call my events.
I don't want to do "window.location.reload();" because of the rapidity, just write my elements without the image, header and nav menu. But if this event doesn't exist, I will do it.

Thank you in advance for the time granted!

And sorry for my bad english i'm beginning :)

Comment: If I understood correctly you are adding some element to page and you want to re find new elements for adding events?

Comment: Yes but some elements are delted and other added so I have to find all the elements

Comment: Best approach for this kind of listeners is binding event listeners to document instead of elements,you can write your events here, so that I can help you

Comment: I write an answer for write the code ;)

Answer (score 0):

That's my code :

The file were is the XML Http request :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add-group").submit(function(e){
        //Don't refresh the page
        e.preventDefault();

        var data = new FormData(this)
        //Transfert data to php
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                //Get the result and set it to json
                var jsonResult = this.response;
                var result = JSON.parse(jsonResult);
                //reload the page if the result is 1
                if(result.success == 1){
                    //Hide the form
                    $("#add-group-modal").modal('hide');

                    //Reload
                    window.location.reload(); // Here, I want to not reload the page and reload the elements from the json file
                }else{
                    let error = document.querySelector('.alertMessage');
                    error.classList.add('show');
                    error.innerHTML = result.message;
                }
            }else if(this.readyState == 4){
                alert("erreur lors de l'execution de la requête");
            }
        }
        
        xhr.open("POST", "/ToDoList/ToDoList/resources/scripts/importJsonGroups.php", true);
        responseType = 'json';
        xhr.send(data);

        return false;
    });
});
```

This is the php script for set the json file :

```
<?php
    $success = 1;
    $msg = "Le fichier a été mis a jour";
    
    if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['color']) && !empty($_POST['color'])){
        //Get the value from the json file of the tasks
        $JsonFile = file_get_contents("../../data/group.json");
        // Converts to an array 
        $jsonArray = json_decode($JsonFile, true);

        $values = array();

        //Set the values for the json file
        $values ['name'] = $_POST['name'];
        $values ['color'] = $_POST['color'];
    
        array_push($jsonArray, $values);
    
        $newJsonArray = json_encode($jsonArray);
    
        try {
            file_put_contents("../../data/group.json", $newJsonArray);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            $success = 0;
            $msg = "fichier introuvable";
        }
    
    }else{
        $success = 0;
        $msg = "veuillez remplir correctement les champs";
    }

    $result = ["success" => $success, "message" => $msg];
    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

And this is the file were are write my elements :

```
$.get("../../../ToDoList/ToDoList/data/group.json", function(data) {
    let groups = new Array(data.length)

    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        groups[i] = data[i]
    }

    if(groups.length > 0){
        let contentGroup = document.querySelector('.contentGroup');
        //Delte the content of the div
        contentGroup.innerHTML = "";
        //Show the elemtents in the div
        groups.forEach(element => {
            contentGroup.innerHTML += `
            <div class="card">
                <a href="index.php?controller=task&action=seeTask&group=${element['name']}">
                    <div class="card-header d-flex">
                        <div class="d-flex ml-2">
                            <span class="icon-copy dw dw-menu row align-self-center" style="color:${element['color']};"></span>
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-block text-left" id="groupName" style="color:${element['color']};">
                            ${element['name']}
                        </button>
                        <div class="d-flex">
                            <span class="icon-copy dw dw-right-chevron row align-self-center"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            `;
        });
    }else{

    }
});
```

This is the html page with the #add-group and .contentGroup :

```
<div class="main-container">
    <!-- Navigation menu -->
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" role="navigation">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Groupes</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>

    <!-- Groupe -->
    <div id="contentPage align-item-left">
        <!-- This is the content group, where i show the elements -->
        <div class="contentGroup"></div>
        <button type="button" id="btnAddGroup" class="btn btn-info addTask">
            <div class="crossHorizontal"></div>
            <div class="crossVertical"></div>
        </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal Comfirm delete -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="confirmation-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body text-center font-18">
                    <h4 class="padding-top-30 mb-30 weight-500">Are you sure you want to continue?</h4>
                    <div class="padding-bottom-30 row" style="max-width: 170px; margin: 0 auto;">
                        <form method="post" class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-around">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary border-radius-100 btn-block confirmation-btn" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                                NO
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary border-radius-100 btn-block confirmation-btn"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
                                YES
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End modal confirm delete -->

    <!-- Modal Add Group -->
    <div id="add-group-modal" class="modal modal-top fade calendar-modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <!-- This is the form #add-group -->
                <form id="add-group" method="post">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h4 class="text-blue h4 mb-10">Ajouter un groupe</h4>
                        <div class="alert alert-danger alertMessage" role="alert">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Nom du groupe</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>
                                Couleur
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="complex-colorpicker form-control" value="#7ab2fa" name="color"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End modal add Group -->

    <script src='/ToDoList/ToDoList/resources/js/custom/addGroupToPage.js'></script>
    <script src='/ToDoList/ToDoList/resources/js/custom/groupsActions.js'></script>
```

And this is what is show in the page :
[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: was better to edit first question and write your codes there.
so what if you run $.get("../../../ToDoList/ToDoList/data/group.json", function(data) { ..... instead of window.location.reload() ?

Comment: I want to do this, but if i do, when i declare the events, the element are not found, like the "#add-group". So i want to know if this method have written all the elements, for call my events in these elements.

PS : sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Please show me rest of your code. #add-group and .contentGroup. never mind, my english is worse than you :))

Comment: according to your code $.get("../../../ToDoList/ToDoList/data/group.json", function(data) { ..... 2wice has to do what you want but if you say it doesn't, so another suggestion is that return new item after sumbit from server and after if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){ ...  use this.responseText then add this new todo to your div.contentGroup